# What resources do an unused CriticalSection or ConditionVariable allocate?

Tags: windows, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

Suppose that I have a CriticalSection/ConditionVariable. I initialize (with `InitializeCriticalSection`/`InitializeConditionVariable`), but never use them (no lock operations, no signal/wait).

Do these unused objects allocate other resources other than the memory they occupy?

If that matters, I'm interested this in Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: `InitializeConditionVariable` not allocate any additional resources. critical section in old windows versions can create event (kernel object). but in new windows versions (how minimum begin from win 8.1). no any objects is created/used for both cs and conditional variables

Comment: @Rbmm, ooh, way older than that. :-)  I believe Windows 2000 was the only version in which the event could be pre-allocated, and even then it only happened if the programmer set a flag asking for it.  See [here](http://www.tenouk.com/crstufunction3.html) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140911-00/?p=44103).  Windows XP and later ignore the flag.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - about per-allocated event yes. event in xp and win 7 allocate on first wait attempt (when enter to critical section fail without wait) and begin from win8.1 event at all no more used (allocated) for cs. new api `ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId` and `ZwAlertThreadByThreadId` use. if thread need wait on cs or conditional variable (or addres or srw lock) it interlocked push to stack it id. and wait by `ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId`. another thread pop this id and call `ZwAlertThreadByThreadId`. no memory/objects allocated